# how to read files from a python module inside docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-swarm

How can I read files within a python module while executing in docker? I have a python module which I import in my code. normally in order to fetch the relative path of the module one can do `<<module_name>>.__path__`. however this approach does not work in docker but works locally.

Is there a  common way in which I can read the files from the module in docker as well as in local?

Comment: Can you provide code to show what you're doing? We need more info to figure out what you're doing.

Comment: `import module_data` # this module has few serialized files

#once module is imported read the files
`route = module_data.__path__[0]`

however the line  `module_data.__path__[0]` does not works in docker, though it works in local(without docker)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider:

1. Where is python installed in the container and what version? Does
   that match your dev environment?
2. Look at your dockerfile - what is your working directory? Did you set one? Perhaps, you are running your python code from one directory, but trying to import a module from another.
3. Is your `PYTHONPATH` set in your container?
4. Have you installed the modules in the container that you're attempting to use? Perhaps with a requirements.txt file or manually? If so, are you executing your python code with the same python version/path that you installed the modules with?
5. Are you using a virtual environment? Has it been sourced?
6. What user is your container running as? Does it have access to the python modules? You may need to `chown` the site-packages path or run as a different user or `root`.